# How do I install the debug Flash player version 11.3?

Tags: flash, debugging, adobe

How do install a debug Flash player now that version check denies it? Adobe is not keeping up on the debug build minor versions. I'm on a new machine and frankly haven't had to debug Flash  in like a year.

I can't install the flash debug player to debug my applications. I downloaded the Windows Flash Player 11.3 Plugin content debugger (for Netscape-compatible browsers) (EXE, 9.94MB). When I ran the debug player installer, it said "this is not the installer for the most recent version" and by golly, the only option is to quit the unpackager/installer.

Is there any way to bypass this version check so that I can debug my application?

Comment: cool, thanks @wvxvw I'm going to try your suggestion when I'm back in the ranks. Put it in an answer so I have the opportunity to accept it if it solves the issue. I'm going to leave my meta-rant in for now because it amuses me, hopefully others. Already worked till 2AM on unrelated shit last night, so zero motivation to be doing this kind of stuff at home over the weekend or Ramadan or Santa or whatever it is right now. Hehe, that's usually my solution anyway, just use the old version cuz it does what it does: bet flash writes to the log on this particular "home" machine, but IDGAF. 
:

Comment: I removed the rant and tried to focus the question to what you really want to know. The rest was completely unnecessary and was hiding your real issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Cleaning the registry after running the uninstaller worked for me.

Just destroy HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia

I could even install older debug versions like 10.xxx

Comment: When talking about Flash, I'd rather destroy keys than removing them.